# How do you stop a custom enchantment from working whe applied to a bow and arrow?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I made an enchantment in Minecraft Forge that poisons the entity that you hit, but it also works with a bow. I don't want that. I want it to work like the fire aspect enchantment. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried to look into the fire aspect code but I couldn't find anything about a bow.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, can you show your code to make a [mre] ?

Answer (score 1):

To make the enchantment only work on melee attacks and not on bows, you need to modify the `canApplyTogether` method of your enchantment class.

Here's how you can do it:

```java
@Override
public boolean canApplyTogether(Enchantment ench) {
    // Don't apply if the other enchantment is an arrow-based enchantment
    if (ench instanceof EnchantmentArrowDamage || ench instanceof EnchantmentArrowFire || ench instanceof EnchantmentArrowInfinite) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.canApplyTogether(ench);
}
```

This method checks if the other enchantment is an arrow-based enchantment (such as `EnchantmentArrowDamage`, `EnchantmentArrowFire`, or `EnchantmentArrowInfinite`) and returns false if it is. Otherwise, it calls the super implementation to check if the enchantment can be applied together with other enchantments.

By overriding this method, you can control which enchantments can be applied together with your custom enchantment. In this case, by preventing arrow-based enchantments from being combined with your poison enchantment, you ensure that it only affects melee attacks.

Comment: you can still use the enchantment on a bow and the arrow will still poison the enemy